# why rgee can not use the right version of python?

Tags: r, python-3.x, apigee, rgee, libgee

I'm trying to use rgee package in Rstudio. I installed reticulate and rgee packages. My python version is 3.7 (I'm very sure about it, installed and checked several times). But when I use ee_check(), it seems the version that was detected is 3.1? I'm so confused about this.

```
> ee_check()
(*)  Python version
√ [Ok] C:/Users/39327/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/rgee/python.exe v3.1
Error in ee_check_python(quiet = quiet) : rgee needs Python 3.5 >=
```

Comment: check your environmental parameter whether it refers to older version. OS type and version info of software would help too. Dump the relevant info from the commandline code  `conda env list` as update in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try your local python environment with the earthengine-api. you can find https://github.com/r-spatial/rgee/tree/help/rstudio/. Please write the "EARTHENGINE_PYTHON="D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"
EARTHENGINE_ENV=NULL" in your ".Renviron" file.
"D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" is my local python path, please change it for your own.